# A Bored Jailer and His Number Game

Tags: strategy

A bored jailer tells a prisoner that if he can guess a secret number he will be set free. The rules are given that the number will **not be more than three digits** in length and the prisoner may guess the number as many times as necessary, as long as his guesses meet one of the following requirements each time:

- Guess contains a digit in the secret number
- Guess has a value less than the secret number

*The prisoner is told which conditions his guesses match.*

**If the secret number is three digits long, which number would take the least guesses?**

**Which guesses would the prisoner use?**

**Which secret number would take the most guesses?**

Comment: I'm confused, if his guess doesnt meet the requirements what happens? You say he can guess as many times as necessary as long as his guess meets the requirements.

Comment: exactly. if the guess doesn't meet the requirements he gets no more guesses. Game over.

Comment: Then what’s the point of telling him which conditions he meets? It always both or game over. Seems pointless.

Comment: lets say he guesses 56 for his first guess. if the number was 47 he loses. if the number is 78 he gets another guess although neither digit is in the answer however he gets another guess because it is less than the answer

Comment: Does the prisoner know if the secret number is 3 digits long, or are we not allowed to make that assumption?

Comment: No, the way you worded it, his guess must meet BOTH requirements to be able to keep guessing.

Comment: the prisoner does not know how many digits. and yes Thomas you are right, i edited the wording

Comment: Is the prisoner told which digits match? Eg: number is 56, prisoner guesses 75, are they told "Not lower, but some digits match" or "Not lower, 5 matches"?

Comment: no, only that a digit does match, not which ones.

Comment: Can the number start with a 0?

Comment: Jens, well no, that wouldn't be a 3 digit number. ie. 056 is 56

Comment: Do we assume that the number to be guessed is 3 *distinct* digits?  Could it, for example, be $222$?

Comment: yes it could be

Comment: Probably I don't understand the question, but why the prisoner cannot use all natural numbers in order (e.g. firstly guess 0, then 1, then 2 etc.)? Since he has unlimited attempts, he will definitely win at some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the actual strategy.

> Prisoner guesses 0-9, noting which three guesses satisfy the number contained requirements. Then wolog $x<y<z$ were his three number matched guesses. Then he guesses yxz or yzx. This strategy takes at most 13 guesses depending on which ordering of x, y, and z is correct.

If the secret number is three digits long, which number would take the least guesses?

> This strategy would take at most six guesses if the number contains 0, 1, and 2.

Which secret number would take the most guesses?

> Any number containing three distinct values having form xy9 or 9yx would take up to 13 guesses.

Comment: well, yes...but i asked which numbers would take the least and most guesses if looked at strategically.

Comment: I'm not a game theorist, but it seems to me that a method which guarantees success better fits the definition of "strategy" than a method which doesn't, especially when there are no move or time constraints. A method is not really a "strategy" unless it yields favorable outcomes. In this case, what you are calling strategy sacrifices guaranteed freedom for the novelty of your solution.

Comment: There are more efficient methods that still guarantee success

Comment: @FrostedSyntax gave it a real shot.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov good job

Comment: I did modify the middle one. Is the green check for the correct strategy or the proper answer to all the questions?

Comment: Well considering it can't start with 0, i realized 123 and 102 would both take 5 guesses. so you're correct either way

Comment: Sorry, but 102 would only take 4 guesses.

Comment: @Jens true. good catch

Comment: After you've gotten x=0, y=1, z=2, you know it either 102, 120, 201, or 210. My strategy said to either pick 120 or 201, and depending which of 102 and 210 it is it is either five or six guesses.

Comment: I chose to guess one of the middle numbers in the ordering to get the least upper bound for guesses. Starting with xyz makes the upper bound 16 guesses if the answer is zyx.

Comment: It would be better to only guess 1-9, then 0 , since zero is the least occurring digit.
Also, this strategy still works with numbers with repeated digits, if the number contains 2 different digits there are still six possible results, and if it contains a single digit, it's trivially that digit repeated three times.

Comment: I don't believe this works as is.  First off, there really isn't a reason the jailer's number couldn't be 057.  Second, and more important, once you guess 000 and get a matched digit and a less than, guessing 001 does not provide a viable test for a 1.  It will always get a matched digit: the 0.  And if you guess 111, and the jailer's number is 105, you lose.

Comment: @DavidG.  OP has stated in comments that leading zeroes don’t count.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov  Even so, the second problem is still CRITICAL

Comment: No, the second issue still concerns leading zeroes. Guessing “1” is NOT guessing “001”.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  If we allow denormalized values like "057", then our first guess is "210", and it takes not more than 9 guesses, and as few as 1 if the secret number was "210".  It takes an average of 7.311 guesses.  (An interesting result: 1/8th of the numbers take a full 9.)

If we don't allow denormalized values, then our first guess is "321", and  it still takes not more than 9 guesses.  It takes an average of 7.09555... guesses.

The strategy starts by observing that every guess splits the space of possibilities five ways.

1. that we guessed the secret number.
2. that we guessed higher than the secret number and didn't match digits, and therefore lost.  We must choose our guesses to make this space empty!
3. that we guessed lower than the secret number, and didn't match digits.
4. that we guessed higher than the secret number, and matched digits.
5. that we guessed lower than the secret number, and matched digits.

The secret is to make the smallest the last three as large as possible.  If we could produce an equal split, we could achieve a win in seven guesses.  We can't get an equal split.

The first guess of 210 or 321 is the largest number that includes all possible first digits of any smaller number, thus guaranteeing no loss, and getting good splits (1/0/343/210/446 or (1/0/294/221/384).  This is the shortest possible guess.

The worst case?  Any that take 9 guesses.  432 and 997 is a good examples as they take 9 with or without denormalized numbers.

I'm not going to try to show a full decision tree, since they are huge.

An ideal strategy might to a bit better than what I've cited, as my testing was done based on finding all possible guesses that got the best split, discarding those that aren't possible secret numbers if any are, and then taking the lowest.

I haven't tried the possibility that we are not told that we have guessed the secret number, and must prove it based on other evidence.  Even that probably won't take more than 10 guesses.